# if a cell (Column A) contains a value/string from column B, then write value/string in column C

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a list of keywords in Columns A, like the following:

ferrari blue 1975
audi 1988 white
black bmw 1989

then I have in Column B car brands, column C colors, column D years.

I want to check if a keyword (column A), contains a certain car brand (column B) to write in a another Column the value matched.
The same then for colors and years.

Can you please help?
Thanks

Comment: pls, share your spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B1:B3), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1:A3), " ", "|")))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. But how can I check A1 with B3, in case - as an example - "ferrari" is in B3?

Comment: or in other words: how can I extract the car brands and list them in column C, even if  - as an example - "ferrari" is present in A1 and B3?